# Big O of a difference

Tags: convergence-divergence, asymptotics

Assume $f,g$ are such that
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=r\in\mathbb{R}.$$
Is there anything non-trivial we can infer about
$$\left|\frac{f}{g}-r\right|$$
in terms of big-O notation, more sharp than
$$\left|\frac{f}{g}-r\right|=O\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)=O(1)?$$

Comment: If you know how _quickly_ the ratio converges to $r$ you would have a big-O notation distinct from $O(1)$. But how about $o(1)$, which is at least a little sharper than $O(1)$?

Comment: I was rather looking for something in terms of $1/f$ or $1/g,$ but it seems I have no hope without more assumptions, which is what I feared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the convergence can be as slow as you want, so you only can say that the difference is bounded in a neighburhood of $+\infty$, that is to say it is a $O(1)$.

Comment: As @David K said, it obviously only concerns the $O$ notation, and $o(1)$ is better.